# window.matchMedia not changing even if media queries are present

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, media-queries, matchmedia

There's a CSS file with these rules:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .foo {}
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .foo {}
}
```

And then I've got this script, running on `orientationchange`:

```
function checkOr(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation:portrait)").matches) {
      console.log('portrait ' + window.orientation);
    } else {
      console.log('landscape '+ window.orientation);
    }
}
```

But matchMedia always returns initial state of the page, when window.orientation returns correct value:

```
portrait -90
portrait 0
portrait -90
```

Tested on iPhone 5 and iPad 4 with latest iOS updates.

What am I doing wrong? 
[Webkit bugtracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75903) says that there must be rules for each media query, but that's not my case.

Comment: the window.matchMedia is bugged on Chrome, after one exits fullscreen mode it will return wrong values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753522/chrome-43-window-size-bug-after-full-screen

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the event to call the function on orientationchange? I just tried this on my iPad and it seems to work fine: http://jsbin.com/ewixuc/2

```
function checkOr(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation:portrait)").matches) {
      alert('portrait ' + window.orientation);
    } else {
      alert('landscape '+ window.orientation);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", checkOr);
```